# My conditions return false even when they should return true

Tags: c++, debugging, codeblocks

I am trying to check the lenght of a string from my clipboard and also the first character of the string and if it returns true, I would like to set the clipboard to a different content. Here is my class;

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <cstring>

namespace Diall_ClipBoard_catch
{
    class ClipBoard
    {
    private:
        ::HANDLE dHDat;
        ::std::string tmpstringsign;
        bool isopen;
        char* dHbuffer;
        char* dHbuffertemp;
        char* dNtoken;
    public:
        ClipBoard(void)
        {
            this->dHbuffer = const_cast <char*>("");
            this->dHbuffertemp = const_cast <char*>("");
            this->tmpstringsign = "dnb_4554_2102";
            this->isopen = false;
        };
        ~ClipBoard(void)
        {

        }
        char* GetData(void)
        {
            this->Start();
            if (this->isopen)
            {
                this->dHDat = ::GetClipboardData(CF_TEXT);

                if (this->dHDat)
                {
                    this->dHbuffer = (char*)::GlobalLock(this->dHDat);

                    if (::std::strcmp(this->dHbuffertemp, this->dHbuffer) != 0 && this->dHbuffer != "" && this->dHbuffer != NULL)
                    {
                        this->dHbuffertemp = this->dHbuffer;
                        //::std::cout << this->dHbuffer << "\n";
                        return this->dHbuffer;
                    }

                    ::GlobalUnlock(this->dHDat);
                }
                CloseClipboard();
                this->isopen = FALSE;
                ::Sleep(1000);
            }
        }
        void SetData(void)
        {
            const char* data = this->dHbuffer;
            const char* newstring = "Hello World";
            const size_t len = strlen(newstring) + 1;
            HGLOBAL hMem = GlobalAlloc(GMEM_MOVEABLE, len);
            memcpy(GlobalLock(hMem), newstring, len);
            GlobalUnlock(hMem);
            if (!OpenClipboard(NULL))
            {
                return;
            }
            if (strlen(data) == 8)
            {
                    if(data[0] == '1' || data[0] == '7')
                    {
                        EmptyClipboard();
                        SetClipboardData(CF_TEXT, hMem);
                    }
            }
            CloseClipboard();
            this->isopen = TRUE;
        }
    private:
        void Start(void)
        {
            if (!OpenClipboard(NULL))
            {
                return;
            }
            this->isopen = true;
        }
    };
}
```

And here is my main.cpp

```
#include "Clipboard.h"

int main()
{
    ::Diall_ClipBoard_catch::ClipBoard* clipboard = new Diall_ClipBoard_catch::ClipBoard();
    int temp1 = 0, temp2 = 0;
    EmptyClipboard();
    while (1)
    {
        temp1 = GetClipboardSequenceNumber();
        if (temp1!= temp2)
        {
            clipboard->SetData();
            std::cout << clipboard->GetData() << std::endl;
        }

        temp2 = temp1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

When I try to echo strlen(data), the value i get is 0 which should not be the case. But i get the first character of the string from data[0] but when I check it against my condition, it always returns false even though it should return as true.

PS. I am an absolute beginner in c++.

Comment: did you use a debugger? The tag is not for any questions about a bug in your code, but for questions sepcifically about debugging. Tag description: "This tag is ONLY for questions about debugging techniques or the process of debugging itself, NOT for requesting help debugging your code. "

Comment: why are you not using `std::string`?

Comment: why you tag your question with the name of the editor. Is it about programming or about using your editor?

Comment: Please read about [mcve]. When you say "When I try to echo strlen(data), the value i get is 0" we don't know what you actually did, because there is nothing like that in your code.

Comment: you must duplicate clipboard contain rather than to save a pointer to (`this->dHbuffer = (char*)::GlobalLock(this->dHDat);` is not a copy but just saving the pointer), you are in C++ use a std::string rather than array of char

Comment: Don't `const_cast` a string literal! It's undefined behaviour if you change the content of a string literal and your program are under no obligation to work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

`dHbuffer` is initialized to point to `""`

In `SetData` you assign `data` to the value of `dhBuffer`, which is pointing to `""`

You then do `strlen(data)`, aka `strlen("")`, which has a length of 0.

Everyone else's advice is pretty solid. It wasn't clear which you "were" when you had your issue, and you should likely be using `std::string`.

Answer (score 0):

In

> ```
>            this->dHDat = ::GetClipboardData(CF_TEXT);
>
>            if (this->dHDat)
>            {
>                this->dHbuffer = (char*)::GlobalLock(this->dHDat);
>
>                if (::std::strcmp(this->dHbuffertemp, this->dHbuffer) != 0 && this->dHbuffer != "" && this->dHbuffer != NULL)
>                {
>                    this->dHbuffertemp = this->dHbuffer;
>                    //::std::cout << this->dHbuffer << "\n";
>                    return this->dHbuffer;
> ```

you do not copy the data but save the (volatile) pointer to `char *`, you need to duplicate it, from [GetClipboardData function documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getclipboarddata) :

> The application should copy the data immediately.

Why are you using array of char ? You are in C++, use `std::string`

[edit for your remark]

using `std::string` the first part of your code becomes (I do not see the usage of *dNtoken* so I let it unchanged) :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <string>

namespace Diall_ClipBoard_catch
{
    class ClipBoard
    {
    private:
        ::HANDLE dHDat;
        ::std::string tmpstringsign;
        bool isopen;
        std::string dHbuffer;
        std::string dHbuffertemp;
        char* dNtoken;
    public:
        ClipBoard(void)
        {
            tmpstringsign = "dnb_4554_2102";
            isopen = false;
            dNtoken = NULL; // better to not let it non initialized
        };
        ~ClipBoard(void)
        {
            // if needed free(dNtoken)
        }
        std::string GetData(void)
        {
            this->Start();
            if (this->isopen)
            {
                this->dHDat = ::GetClipboardData(CF_TEXT);

                if (this->dHDat)
                {
                    this->dHbuffer = (char*)::GlobalLock(this->dHDat);

                    if ((this->dHbuffertemp != this->dHbuffer) && !this->dHbuffer.empty())
                    {
                        this->dHbuffertemp = this->dHbuffer;
                        //::std::cout << this->dHbuffer << "\n";
                        return this->dHbuffer;
                    }

                    ::GlobalUnlock(this->dHDat);
                }
                CloseClipboard();
                this->isopen = FALSE;
                ::Sleep(1000);
            }
        }
        void SetData(void)
        {
            std::string data = this->dHbuffer;
            const char* newstring = "Hello World";
            const size_t len = strlen(newstring) + 1;
            HGLOBAL hMem = GlobalAlloc(GMEM_MOVEABLE, len);
            memcpy(GlobalLock(hMem), newstring, len);
            GlobalUnlock(hMem);
            if (!OpenClipboard(NULL))
            {
                return;
            }
            if (data.length() == 8)
            {
                    if(data[0] == '1' || data[0] == '7')
                    {
                        EmptyClipboard();
                        SetClipboardData(CF_TEXT, hMem);
                    }
            }
            CloseClipboard();
            this->isopen = TRUE;
        }
    private:
        void Start(void)
        {
            if (!OpenClipboard(NULL))
            {
                return;
            }
            this->isopen = true;
        }
    };
}
```

Additional note, you do not need to write `this->` in all the code above

Comment: How do I duplicate it? and when I tried using `std::string` for `dHbuffer` i got the **cannot convert 'std::__cxx11::string' {aka 'std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>'} to 'const char*'|** error.

Comment: @KingKesh you have to use `std::string` for *dHbuffer* and *dHbuffertemp* and no `::std::strcmp` but just `==` etc, you message indicate you go back to a `char*` from a `std::string`. ELse continue with your `char*``but `strcpy``to make a copy

Comment: Can you show me an example of what you mean? it's a bit confusing

Comment: @KingKesh I edited my answer. Note I do not use Windows so I have no way to check

Comment: I mean you can show me how that line of code for strcpy() should look like

Comment: @KingKesh `this->dHbuffer = strdup((char*)::GlobalLock(this->dHDat));` **but** because you just use `char*` pointers you also have to manage yourself the necessary  `free` of previously read and duplicated strings, else you introduce memory leaks, and to take care to not liberate several times the same string nor to liberate a string save elsewhere ... this is why it is much more simple and secure to use `std::string` whose do all that work for you